# 1 rep user 'creates' tag?

Tags: support, tags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268285/ios-enterprise-license

How does this happen? Perhaps if a tag has no questions, it should take as much rep to use it as it does to create a new one?

So, it turns out that I was mislead for the 17th time by the interaction of the 'featured' tab with clicking on a tag. I find this completely counter-intuitive. When I am looking at a specific question, and click on one of its tags, I expect to see all the questions with that tag, not just 'featured' ones. Grumble.

Comment: How can you tell that user created [tag:enterprise-development]? Looks like it [goes back to 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/210455/1)

Comment: Which tag are you referring to? 147 questions are tagged with [tag:enterprise-development], which is the only tag I see there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The tag *does* have questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enterprise-development)

Perhaps you were on the featured tab at that time?

Comment: I DO hate getting stuck on that Featured tab

Comment: Drat, yes I was. I have no idea how I got there.

Comment: @Rosinate iirc if you go to featured on the main page, the tags automatically flip.